# 19.04 settings not showing up in Unity Control Center

Tags: unity, touchpad

I am trying to turn on the touchpad while typing in my Ubuntu 19.04 computer, but in Unity Control Center only 3 icons show up. They are:

1. Language Support
2. Sharing
3. Software and Updates

If I run as root, I get the first one, the last one, and Printers.

I looked for the touchpad while typing option in GNOME settings, but the setting isn't there. How do I fix this, or turn on touchpad while typing?

Comment: What does `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` return?

Comment: It says ubuntu:gnome. However, GNOME settings doesn't have what I am looking for.

Comment: But `unity-control-center` is designed to be used in a Unity session, and you are in an Ubuntu session. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Using the touchpad while typing. It isn't in the control center that comes with Ubuntu

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-touchpad-click.html

Comment: That doesn't say anything about using the pad while typing.

Comment: `gnome-control-center` > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad.  By default the touchpad is 'usable' while typing, what's disabled while typing is  `tap to click' . This is hard-coded in, no option to change. You'll need to search out how to enable tap to click at all times in libinput (- if that's what you want?

Comment: I am trying to play minecraft with the touchpad. It has two click buttons, but I can't turn while moving due to the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you want to use *Tweaks*. If you haven't already, you should install Tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then open it, select *Keyboard & Mouse*, and find a *Disable While Typing* switch.